# ag-grid with typescript and angular - usage of type definitions

Tags: ag-grid

I am curious how to work with ag-grid and angular and typescript in a typed manner.

In the examples I don't see the usage of any type definitions e.g. when using columnDefs, callbacks (gridReady, firstDataRendered) or valueGetter functions and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php) and [repo](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid)?

> **`columnDefs`** [ColDef](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/packages/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/entities/colDef.d.ts#L63)

*its too big to copy, just check `ColDef` interface inside `ag-grid/packages/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/entities/colDef.d.ts`*

> **`gridReady`** [AgGridEvent](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/packages/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/events.d.ts#L28)

```
export interface AgEvent {
    type: string;
}
export interface AgGridEvent extends AgEvent {
    api: GridApi;
    columnApi: ColumnApi;
}
```

> **`firstDataRendered`** [FirstDataRenderedEvent](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/packages/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/events.d.ts#L115)

```
export interface FirstDataRenderedEvent extends AgGridEvent {
    firstRow: number;
    lastRow: number;
}
```

> **`valueGetter`** [ValueGetterParams](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/packages/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/entities/colDef.d.ts#L298)

```
export interface BaseColDefParams {
    node: RowNode;
    data: any;
    colDef: ColDef;
    column: Column;
    api: GridApi;
    columnApi: ColumnApi;
    context: any;
}
export interface ValueGetterParams extends BaseColDefParams {
    getValue: (field: string) => any;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I found this type definitions. But the import only worked in a very weird way (e.g. import {
    BaseColDefParams,
    ValueFormatterParams
} from '../../../../../../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/entities/colDef';
Only some types were able to import as expected e.g. 
import { GridApi, GridReadyEvent, GridOptions } from 'ag-grid-community';

And every official example I saw had no type definition at all.

So I am curious how others handle this in an angular app...

Comment: `import { ValueSetterParams } from 'ag-grid-community/dist/lib/entities/colDef';`
seems clear enough